# Why do we need `iteratoreltype()`?

Tags: julia

I am not sure I understand why `IteratorEltype()` is needed. Every iterable is guaranteed to produce objects of type `Any`, so if you don't know any better then you can always default to that. What is the point of distinguishing between "I know it could be anything" (`IteratorEltype == HasEltype && eltype = Any`) and "I don't know what it is, hence it could be anything" (`IteratorEltype == EltypeUnknown`)?

The only type in Base Julia which uses `EltypeUnknown()` I could find is `Generator`, which is the tool behind the `(f(i) for i in iter)` syntax. I can imagine that it is hard / impossible to find the `eltype` of such a generator if `eltype(iter)` is a non-leaf type, but what is the advantage of not simply setting the `eltype` to `Any` in this case? Of course, you wouldn't want it to be `Any` if `eltype(iter)` is a leaf-type and `f` is type-stable, but those two cases should be distinguishable at compile-time.

Comment: A quick `grep` in `base` directory says `array.jl` and `reduce.jl` use `iteratoreltype`. Both for reasons of compile-time optimization and decision making.

Comment: Yes, but what exactly can you optimise this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two `IteratorEltype()` options is as follows:

- `HasEltype()` says that the values of the iterator should be treated as objects of type `eltype()`, even if `eltype()` is more general than the types actually encountered in the iterator.
- `EltypeUnknown()` asks functions like `collect()` to figure out the most specific type applicable to all elements.

---

**Example:**

```
julia> abstract type Wrapper end
       Base.length(w::Wrapper) = length(w.data)
       Base.iterate(w::Wrapper, s...) = iterate(w.data, s...)

       struct EltypeWrapper{T,D} <: Wrapper
           data::D
       end
       EltypeWrapper{T}(data) where T = EltypeWrapper{T,typeof(data)}(data)
       Base.eltype(::Type{<:EltypeWrapper{T}}) where T = T

       struct EltypeUnknownWrapper{D} <: Wrapper
           data::D
       end
       Base.IteratorEltype(::Type{<:EltypeUnknownWrapper}) = Base.EltypeUnknown()

julia> collect(EltypeWrapper{Any}(Any[1,2.0]))
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 1  
 2.0

julia> collect(EltypeUnknownWrapper(Any[1,2.0]))
2-element Array{Real,1}:
 1  
 2.0
```

Note that the two arrays have the same entries, but the first has type `Vector{Any}` while the second has type `Vector{Real}`.

---

It may seem that `HasEltype()` should be more efficient because it allows for preallocation of the output in functions like `collect()`. Julia is pretty good at inferring the iterator eltype, however, and `EltypeUnknown()` can be as fast as (or for some weird reason even faster than) `HasEltype()`:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

       abstract type AbstractIterable end
       struct TypedIterable <: AbstractIterable; end
       struct UntypedIterable <: AbstractIterable; end
           
       Base.length(::AbstractIterable) = 100000

       Base.eltype(::Type{TypedIterable}) = Int
       Base.IteratorEltype(::Type{UntypedIterable}) = Base.EltypeUnknown()

       function Base.iterate(f::AbstractIterable,i = 1)
           i > length(f) && return nothing
           return i, i+1
       end

       @btime collect(UntypedIterable())
       @btime collect(TypedIterable())
       ;
  43.033 μs (2 allocations: 781.33 KiB)
  56.772 μs (2 allocations: 781.33 KiB)
```

`IteratorEltype()` thus not necessarily impacts the performance of working with the iterator, but it may heavily impact the performance further up in the call stack. Almost all code is order of magnitudes faster if it operates on leaf types, thus in can be much faster to put `EltypeUnknown()` as the `IteratorEltype()` and hope that the `eltype()` boils down to a concrete type rather than to set `IteratorEltype() = HasEltype()` and then set `eltype()` to some abstract type.